# Simple subgroups of a symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

In class we used in an exercise that "the only simple subgroup of a symmetric group (if it has one) is the alternating subgroup". But I don't understand where this comes from. Can  someone help me?

Comment: That statement is not true. Every finite simple group is a subgroup  of a symmetric group.

Comment: What is true is that the only simple *normal* subgroup of a symmetric group $S_n, n \ge 5$ is the alternating group. This follows from the fact that the alternating group $A_n$ is simple (for $n \ge 5$).